# how this works in oop java?

Tags: java, oop

This code is working with me correctly, but how did this happened ? How did i made 4 objects of `JMenu` named the same name which is (menu)? I need to understand even if it worked and is this code a good way of writing code or there is better ?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final String TITLE = "DevTools";
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem menuitem;
    private String[] menu_titles = {"File", "Edit", "Diagrams", "Help"};

    public Window(){
        init();
        createMenu();
    }

    public void init(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle(TITLE);
    }

    public void createMenu(){
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        for(int j = 0; j < menu_titles.length; j++){
            menu = new JMenu(menu_titles[j]);
            menubar.add(menu);
        }

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how did i made 4 objects of JMenu named the same name which is (menu)

`menu` is not the name of any object.
`menu` is just the variable you used to temporarily store a reference to each newly created `JMenu` instance. You can assign any number of references to it. It will hold just the latest of them in the end.

Since each `JMenu` intance you create is added to the `menubar` `JMenuBar`, you end up with a menu bar that contains multiple `JMenu` instances.

Answer (score 1):

> how did i made 4 objects of JMenu named the same name which is (menu)

You didn't. You used the `menu` instance field four times, overwriting the previous value of it each time. It's left referring to the last `JMenu` you assigned to it.

`menu`, in that code, shouldn't be an instance field at all. It should be a local variable in `createMenu` (or even inside the `for` loop in `createMenu`), because it shouldn't be used once `createMenu` is complete and you've added all the menus to the menu bar.

Comment: do u mean i declare private JMenu menu inside the function createmenu ?  wouldn't i use it again when i set key listeners on it ?

Comment: @AhmedNader: Yes, that's what I meant. You'd either assign the key listeners in `createMenu`'s `for` loop, or get the `JMenu` instances from your `JMenuBar` as necessary, or keep them in an array that you keep in an instance field.

Comment: i guess i will move it inside the createMenu() function and add the listeners to them inside it as you said ... thank you for your help .. i thought i know OOP well but now i guess not :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two term in `JAVA` and there is big difference between these two terms actually. So Please don't confuse between these two terms are:----

1. Reference Variable.
2. Actual Object.

   **private JMenu menu;** // here menu is a reference variable not a Object.

   **menu = new JMenu(menu_titles[j]);** // **New** Keyword is responsible to Create a Object. This new Object reference is actually holded by `menu` reference` Variables.

> Now time to explaining the loop code where u actually get confused

```
         for(int j = 0; j < menu_titles.length; j++){
            menu = new JMenu(menu_titles[j]); // at each iteration
              // new keyword is responsible to creating a different Object. 
             //and refers to menu reference variable actually.
            menubar.add(menu); //add new JMenu to menubar.
        }
```

> **Explanation**  :- In each iteration `new` keyword is responsible to creating a different `Object`. and refers to menu reference variable actually. `menubar.add(menu);` this part of code adding new `menu` object members to `menubar`.
>
> Its just think like that there are 3-4 members are standing in row and passing things to the next and final person is throwing the things into a `beanbox`. each iteration same thing is passing through different person but things is remains the same only reference is changed and final position of that thing is a `beanbox`.

Here `beanbox`  menubar which can hold multiple `menu` **Object**. and Person who is passing the things is just like a reference Variables.

Read Carefully u will got this concept. Thank You.. :)

Comment: thank you alot . i didnt know that my own code had all that explanation . all what i know is that i guess this way is good way for using resources :)  thanks for your explanation .